# Wrong parameter count for mysql_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve 7 columns from my Pages table, however it comes up with this error: Wrong parameter count for mysql_fetch_assoc()

I must be using the wrong function, which would be the correct one to use?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM Pages";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
?>

<?php
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
$f1 =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result,$i,"Page","URL","Description","Bounce_Rate",
                         "Avg_Time_On_Page","Page_Views","Click_Rate");
$array[] = $f1;
$i++;
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: you are using right function wrong way. An example of the right way can be easily seen in the manual. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) on the result of the query:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT foo, bar FROM fooTable" );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  echo $row['foo']; // $row['bar'] also available
}
```

Note the signature of this function in the documentation:

> array mysql_fetch_assoc ( resource $result )

This means the function returns an `array` as its result. And it accepts only one parameter, which must be a `resource`. A `resource` is that which is returned from [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). We know this by checking the signature of that method as well:

> resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

This method returns a `resource` (which can be used with [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)), and accepts at least one parameter (the query), with the optional second parameter of a link identifier (that is, your connection to a database).

When in doubt, check the documentation. Also `mysql_numrows` should be [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc() wants only a parameter that is the result of a mysl_query();

Answer (score 0):

What Jonathan said. Also, the rows counting function is mysql_num_rows(), not mysql_numrows().